# Ordering 2d array in lexical order

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have an 2d array of char, and I am trying to order them in alphabetical order. In each rows there is a word build of chars and I am trying to sort it.
I built something, but I don't understand why this is not working. If you have a solution for me, please explain what you are doing, in order to understand why I don't success.
Thanks !

```
char matrix[4][5] = {
                {'h','e','l','l','o'},
                {'r','e','a','d','y'},
                {'a','p','p','l','e'},
                {'p','o','i','n','t'},
                
    };
    char temp;
    bool flag = false;

    display(matrix);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4 - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < 10-1; rows++)
    {
        flag = false;
        for (int cols = 0; cols < 5; cols++)
        {
            if (matrix[rows][cols] > matrix[rows + 1][cols])
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
                {
                        temp=matrix[rows][index];
                        matrix[rows][index]=matrix[rows+1][index];
                        matrix[rows+1][index]=temp;
                }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use another array to "sort" the matrix?  There are ways to do what you want without actually sorting the 2D array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's it.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

char matrix[4][5] = {
    {'h','e','l','l','o'},
    {'r','e','a','d','y'},
    {'a','p','p','l','e'},
    {'p','o','i','n','t'} };

int n = 4, m = 5, k = 0;// number of rows and columns
char temp;

int main()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        for ( int j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
        {
            k = 0;

            while ( matrix[i][k] == matrix[j][k] && k < m )
                k++;

            if ( k < m && matrix[i][k] > matrix[j][k] ) // ASCII code comparison
                for ( int k = 0; k < m; k++ )
                {
                    temp = matrix[i][k];
                    matrix[i][k] = matrix[j][k];
                    matrix[j][k] = temp;
                }
        }

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < m; j++ )
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have to do this only using simple array

Comment: @AndreiRagman The `std::sort` works with simple arrays.  There is no need to store the values in a vector.

Comment: Can you use the matrix like that: `char matrix[4][7] = { "hello", "ready", "apple", "point" };` ?

Comment: No, because the user have to insert every char. I do this array in order to don't write all the time the same thing when I want to execute. And how can you use this array as a char it's not a string ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, but if I'm not allowed to use `std::vector`, I thought that `std::sort` is not allowed either.

Comment: @codingbest ok!

Comment: @codingbest *No, because the user have to insert every char* -- Arrays are not expandable.  What do you mean by "insert every char"?  Is the array fixed at 4 rows and 5 characters?  If not, please amend the original question.

Comment: yes the array is fixed. User have to insert in my example four word or 5 chars

Comment: I've edited the answer. Now it's working with simple arrays.

Comment: This code breaks when k ==m. Better to use strncmp or string::operator<(). Don't reinvent une velo.

Answer (score 0):

I will post this answer, even if it may not be what you want to do (but will be helpful for others who may want to do things this way).

Instead of sorting the 2D array, the trick is to not sort it, and instead sort an array of indices that point into the array.  That is much more simpler than trying to manipulate the array itself.

Here is a very simple example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char matrix[4][5] = {
                    {'h','e','l','l','o'},
                    {'r','e','a','d','y'},
                    {'a','p','p','l','e'},
                    {'p','o','i','n','t'},

    };

    // create the indices
    int index[] = { 0,1,2,3 };

    // sort the indices based on the data in the array 
    std::sort(index, index + 4, [&](int n1, int n2) 
          { return strncmp(matrix[n1], matrix[n2], 5) < 0; });

    // Output the results
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        // Note how we access the original matrix using the index array
        std::cout.write(matrix[index[i]], 5);

        std::cout << " -- Using array at row " << index[i] << "\n";                    
   }
}
```

Output:

```
apple -- Using array at row 2
hello -- Using array at row 0
point -- Using array at row 3
ready -- Using array at row 1
```

The final results show that the indices just point to the row that would be used if we want to access the array in a sorted manner.  The original array was not adjusted.